# Rings and ideals

Tags: ring-theory, ideals

My question is :

Let $R$ be a ring and $p$ prime. Then show that the set
$$ M = \{x \in R: \text{$p^k x = 0$ for some $ k\ge 0$} \} $$
is an ideal of $R$. I have to show that

1. $M$ is closed under addition
2. $ rm \in M $ and  $mr \in R $ for all $ r \in R $ and $m \in M $.

But how?

Comment: $p$ is a prime integer or a prime element of $R$?

Answer (score 1):

Let $n$ be an integer, $r,s\in R$

1. $n(r+s)=nr+ns$
2. $n(rs)=(nr)s=r(ns)$
3. If $p^kr=0$, then $p^hr=0$ for $h\ge k$.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt response. But could you write it more clearly? How did you prove those 2 conditions on being an ideal?

Comment: @FatihGÜLEÇ You can use those properties for proving the set is an ideal.

Answer (score 1):

For any $x\in M$ let $k_x$ be a positive integer such that $p^{k_x}x=0$.

i) For $k=\max\{k_x,k_y\}$, what is $p^k(x+y)$?

ii) What is $p^{k_m}rm$?